# Integrate React Native with Existing Android App

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

When I followed the official tutorial to integrate React Native with my existing Android app, I got this problem. I wanna know how to deal with it. Hope that someone could help me, thanks.

[image: Screenshot of error: Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin]

I tried too many methods which I got online, like changing the edition of Kotlin, etc. But I still can't deal with it.

Comment: Don't post images of errors, copy paste the text  here when it's an error message (posting pictures of graphical bugs is of course fine).